# How to display UIAlertView in iphone app that contain non english message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

am building an iphone app and I have faced a problem when I use non English language to display in UIAlertview. xcode considers the text as code error, so id doesn't recognize the language of the text.
to be more specific am trying to display Arabic language. I don't want to turn the button to arabic I  just want to show alert view that contain few lines of english and few lines of arabic 
my code is work fine with english text but it doesn't when I include the arabic text. 
thanks

Comment: show how you are setting the text, setting arabic shouldnt be a problem

Comment: Have you tried with my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem to show non english content in `UIAlertView` if the language is supportable -

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"هذا هو رسالة غير الإنجليزية." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
```